# How do you correctly return Location headers and do HATEOAS with Apigee?

Tags: apigee

Our Apigee configuration looks a little like this:

Netscaler LB -> Apigee Router/Message Processor -> Netscaler LB - Target Server(s)

The target server in this case is a Java appliation with Jersey, and I'm using the Jersey @Context to retrieve the relevant URI info to set for example Location headers, but all the request details seem to relate to the Netscaler and not the originating request.

If we use an AssignMessage policy and manually set the X-Forwarded-Host URL to be the URL the client calls then everything works as it should do. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a variable we can use instead of hardcoding this - everything in the docs around the variables seems to indicate you can only get the paths after the domain itself.

Comment: I am essentially trying to do what is done in this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Id_yQ5e6sgw - but without the hardcoded part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While in the `<ProxyEnpoint>` request segment, you can reference the variable `request.header.host` and it will give you the host that the client requested into Apigee.

For example, if you URI is https://myorg-test.apigee.net/resource, `request.header.host` in the request segment of the ProxyEndpoint will have a value of `myorg-test.apigee.net`.

If you try to reference this in the `TargetEndpoint`, it may already be overwritten to with the backend host for the target request.  If you need it in the TargetEndpoint, assign it to a variable first in the `ProxyEndpoint/PreFlow/Request` and you can later reference the variable `originalHost`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<AssignMessage async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="grabOriginalHost">
    <AssignVariable>
        <Name>originalHost</Name>
      <Ref>request.header.host</Ref>
    </AssignVariable>
    <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>true</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
    <AssignTo createNew="false" transport="http" type="request"/>
</AssignMessage>
```

Comment: Thanks - so would you recommend using this value rather than X-Forwaded-Host then? I find that X-Forwarded-Host also works, as long as it is set on the Netscaler that sits in front of Apigee.