# How to force apigee proxy to rewrite response URLs from target URL to proxy URL with base path

Tags: apigee

I've created proxy for my REST API:

- Default Target Endpoint URL: http://products.example.com
- Default Proxy Endpoint Base Path: /products/v2
- Proxy URL: http://example.apigee.net/products/v2

When you call target endpoint directly, example:

```
POST http://products.example.com/items
```

you'll get response with location header like this

```
http://products.example.com/items/123131
```

But if I go through proxy:

```
POST http://example.apigee.net/products/v2/items
```

then location header for newly created resource still points to target URL:

```
http://products.example.com/items/3423423
```

But I expected to get

```
http://example.apigee.net/products/v2/items/3423423
```

The question is: how to configure proxy to rewrite URLs in response to Proxy URLs?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps much but I raised a very similar question to yours at [How do you correctly return Location headers and do HATEOAS with Apigee?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572542/how-do-you-correctly-return-location-headers-and-do-hateoas-with-apigee). We ended up needing to write our own policy which does a simple search and replace on the response received from the target server. It would be nice if something was provided out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Apigee proxy allows you to add policies in the response part of a flow. Example below:

```
<Flows>
        <Flow name="myFlow">
            <Description></Description>
            <Request/>
            <Response>
               <Step>
                    <Name>ModifyLocationHeaderPolicy</Name>
               </Step>
            <Response/>
        </Flow>
</Flows>
```

I suggest you to add a javascript or python or java callout policy which will read the Location header of the response and re-write it. Something to the effect like below in Javascript

```
locationHeader = context.getVariable("message.header.Location");
// modify it
 context.setVariable("message.header.Location", locationHeader);
```

Comment: Thank you. I hoped that I don;t have to code it manually. Is my problem so rare, that there is no built-in policy for that?
What about HATEOAS? Nobody use it with apigee?
And what about this statement from apigee:
" Use out-of-the-box policies where possible, and avoid the temptation to code all of your API proxy logic in JavaScript. Even though Apigee Edge leverages compiled JavaScript to improve performance, it is unlikely that JavaScript will perform as well as Policies."
Source: http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/programming-api-proxies-javascript

Comment: @Pitor Bochynski - I completely agree to your points here. It is not a rare situation.